# How do I turn the pivot point off?

Tags: camera

I turned pivot point on at one point trying to use it but I definitely don't like the way the camera feels, how do I turn this off and go back to the normal free camera where I can go up and down with Q,E, and move around freely?

Appreciate any answers, this is driving me crazy and I can't continue until it is fixed.

Comment: By free camera it sounds like you are referring to *Walk Navigation* (Shift F). However this is a modal operator and can only be used temporarily as you can't do anything else while it's running. Which makes me suspect you might mean something else (walk mode definitely isn't the default)

Comment: By camera do you mean the camera object used for rendering or the 3d view?

Comment: I'm really not sure what it was but it was how blender came default, these camera modes just don't feel right in the way they rotate. Sorry I really don't know more about the camera mode I'm looking for but I am pretty new still.

Comment: @Dkace By default blender uses a turntable style of rotation (options in Ctrl Alt U > *User preferences > Input*). But AFAIK the only mode where Q and E move up and down is walk navigation (FPS style).

Answer (score 2):

Moving the camera with the <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> keys is part of the [view navigation](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/navigating/3d_view.html#view-navigation) controls, not part of the pivot point choice.

The effect of the keys is different depending on whether you are using walk or fly mode and the controls are described in [more detail here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Dfelinto/Walk_mode). The default mode can be started with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and either fly and walk mode can be chosen directly from *View> Navigation> Fly Navigation* or *View> Navigation> Walk Navigation*.

> This navigation mode [*walk*] behaves similar to the first person navigation system available in most 3d world games nowadays. It works with a combination of keyboard keys (<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) and mouse movement. By default the navigation is in the 'free' mode, with no gravity influence. You can toggle between gravity and free mode during the navigation (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>).
>
> You can:
> Move the mouse left/right to pan the view left/right or
> move the mouse up/down to tilt the view up/down.
> Move the camera forward/backward (<kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>).
> Strafe left/right (<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd>).
> Jump (<kbd>V</kbd>) - only in 'gravity' mode.
> Move up and down (<kbd>Q</kbd>/<kbd>E</kbd>) - only in 'free' mode.
> Alternate between 'free' and 'gravity' modes (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>).